# Handling the application in dock

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm using Mac OSX 10.9. I made the settings in system preferences->Dock->select "Minimise windows into application icon". The desktop application(objective c) which i created opens a popup window on clicking a button. Once minimised that popup window to the dock i'm unable to maximise it again.  Even i tried the function - (BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen. But its not responding.

Please help me to resolve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Step one: run the app in the debugger and place breakpoints at "interesting" places and examine the app's state.

Comment: how can this question be iOS-related...?

Comment: i'm not able to debug since when i open the popup window, control is not reaching any delegate method. can u please suggest the proper delegate method